# FINDSTR in FOR loop with variables as strings (Batch File)

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, batch-processing

It's my first post here, unfotrtunately question to you instead of help.

I'm writing small program which moves text and pdf files when string is found in text file.(1.txt, 1.txt.pdf ...) It was working very good when i had variables manually set in batch like this :

```
set c1=xxx
set p1=c:\test\xxx\
set c2=yyy
set p2=c:\test\yyy\

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR /i /m "%c1%" "c:\test\*.txt"') DO (
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" MOVE %%A "%p1%">nul
MOVE %%A.pdf %p1%  

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR /i /m "%c2%" "c:\test\*.txt"') DO (
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" MOVE %%A "%p2%">nul
MOVE %%A.pdf %p2%
```

Now I'm trying to use input file with variables :

```
for /F "delims=^ tokens=1,2" %%A in (c:\test\db\input.cdb) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set c!vidx!=%%A & set p!vidx!=%%B
```

It works good, but the problem starts when I try to use for loop for all this variables. Literally search for all (c1,c2,c3...) variables and move them to (p1,p2,p3,...) paths.

Input.cdb looks like this :

```
xxx ^ c:\test\xxx
yyy ^ c:\test\yyy
```

Code:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "delims=^ tokens=1,2" %%A in (c:\test\db\input.cdb) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set c!vidx!=%%A & set p!vidx!=%%B
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%D IN ('FINDSTR /i /m "%c!vidx!%" "c:\test\*.txt"') DO (
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" MOVE %%D "%p!vidx!%">nul
MOVE "%%D.pdf" "%p!vidx!%"
ECHO %%D File is being procesed now
)
)
```

I don't know why this code doesn't work, maybe because there is loop inside loop? 
Or how to create loop to do the same from 0 to how many lines of variables has been read from input.cdb?

I've tried to run this in separate for loop with temporary variable but it's still not using my string and path variables.

Thank you in advance for any help! 
With Regards
Blackfusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh. More than one problem, and what is the appropriate solution?

First item  is a matter of logical design. Let's assume that the batch worked as intended. `c!vidx!` would be set to `%%A` and `p!vidx!` to `%%B`, so unless there's some unpublished use for `c...` and `p...` then you could simply substitute as follows:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "delims=^ tokens=1,2" %%A in (c:\test\db\input.cdb) do (
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%D IN ('FINDSTR /i /m "%%A" "c:\test\*.txt"') DO (
  IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" MOVE %%D "%%B">nul
  MOVE "%%D.pdf" "%%B"
  ECHO %%D File is being procesed now
 )
)
```

Now - there's a common fundamental misconception about `%var%` where `var` is any variable (including `%ERRORLEVEL%` and `%C!vidx!%`...) - a `%VAR%` occurring in a compound statement (or "block") - within the parentheses if a `FOR...DO (in here)` or `IF...(here) ELSE (or here)` is replaced with that variable's value **at the time the outermost statement is parsed - before it is executed.** If `delayedexpansion` is invoked (as you have) then `!var!` refers to the `run-time` value and `%var%` to the `parse-time` value.

Hence, `if "%errorlevel%"=="0"` would be evaluated according to the state of `errorlevel` when the `for...%%A` was parsed, not the value as set by the `findstr`.

This can be corrected by

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "delims=^ tokens=1,2" %%A in (c:\test\db\input.cdb) do (
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%D IN ('FINDSTR /i /m "%%A" "c:\test\*.txt"') DO (
  IF not errorlevel 1 MOVE %%D "%%B">nul
  MOVE "%%D.pdf" "%%B"
  ECHO %%D File is being procesed now
 )
)
```

Where `IF not errorlevel 1` is interpreted as `if the CURRENT (run-time) errorlevel is NOT (1 or greater than 1)`

Comment: Magoo, thank you for good explanation! Now that make so much sense. It's not easy to write batch scripts, but since I just need a simple program to move files it's good enough to program it.